# Dropbox Public Folder's links and privacy?

Tags: dropbox

I've been using the same Dropbox account since 2012, way before default Public folder was removed by Dropbox.

Were/are there any ways for people to access a Public folder and the media in it without having their links?

I never shared my files links.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox links never show up anywhere until you share with others.

You can see after clicking share button it will give you lengthy link.
it is because of difficult to guess.

So don't worry.